# 'Can I use' label's "for" attribute functionality

Tags: html

Having Googled to no avail, I wondered if anyone knows of a list (similar to those of [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) that indicates browser support for the `for` attribute of a `label` tag?

Specifically the functionality that allows a user to click a label and have the associated input (checkbox for example) to be ticked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support has been excellent for years. So excellent that such a list is unnecessary.

Even if support wasn't available, the control itself would still be clickable so it wouldn't be a great loss.

Answer (score 0):

Just put like this.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="..">Choice 1</label>
```

When you click the label, it will check the radio/checkbox

Comment: The question is "How well is this supported?" not "What is the alternative syntax for this?" It is worth pointing out that this syntax is not as well supported as using the for attribute (IIRC it fails in IE-old).